# Oracle Workspace manager - maximum number of workspaces

Tags: oracle

We are exploring the use of Oracle Workspace Manager, and our use case is a bit outside what I think was the intention of the system, so I was hoping for some feedback - either is this conceptually ok, or is there a better way?

We are redoing our budgeting and planning system. As part of the planning process, we create these scenarios where different options are explored. In some cases, these scenarios form the basis for other scenarios, in other cases they do not. However, these scenarios are not temporary areas, they are permanent and must continue to exist forever. So, we would not be merging changes back into the live workspace. This means a proliferation of workspaces, and also that we would need to write reports that compare workspaces. We are looking into the various metadata views to explore how to make these comparisons, and while it is straightforward to do so it does not seem terribly convenient. This makes me wonder if we are going about it incorrectly.

The other major use case is the tracking of revisions to the budget as part of a work planning process. Users can make revisions, submit them for approval, and then once they are approved, they must be preserved so that whatever changes were made can be later easily identified and reported on. We are struggling to decide if we want a workspace for each of these things (which potentially would be many hundreds of workspaces for a planning period) or if we can do something with savepoints.

we are on 11g.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Chris

Comment: I know this is an old question, Chris -- but did you ever find an answer to it?